# Empty Confusion Matrix and Zero Precision/F-score

Tags: neural-network, classification, tensorflow, confusion-matrix, binary-classification

Could you please say why I'm getting this warning while doing a binary classification using Artificial Neural Networks? The data are colored images.

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use the zero_division parameter to control this behavior.
```

And the confusion matrix remains entirely empty for one label.

**Actions I've taken:**
I'm using the stratify parameter when splitting the data into training and testing sets to maintain class proportions. I've checked the test data, and both labels have a sufficient number of samples. The data isn't heavily imbalanced either. The ratio between the two classes is 1/3 (class 0) and 2/3 (class 1)."
[image]

Comment: The warning explicitly says "labels with no **predicted** samples". I suspect something is wrong with your model and it always outputs the same prediction. Can you provide more information?

Comment: It would help us help you solve this issue if you shared a minimal amount of code you're using to generate the confusion matrix and an example of the target and predictions you're passing to it.